# From 10 years of data, I want to select only calendar days with max or min value

Tags: pandas, datetime

Ok, so I have a dataset of temperatures for each day of the year, over a period of ten years. Index is date converted to datetime.

I want to get a dataset with only the min and max value for each calendar day throughout the 10-year period.

I can convert the index to a string, remove the year and get the dataset that way, but I'm guessing there is a smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `min` and `max`:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
d = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2010-12-31')
df = pd.DataFrame({"temp": np.random.randint(0, 30, size=len(d))}, index=d)
print(df)
            temp
2000-01-01     0
2000-01-02     8
2000-01-03     3
2000-01-04    22
2000-01-05     3
         ...
2010-12-27    16
2010-12-28    10
2010-12-29    28
2010-12-30     1
2010-12-31    28

[4018 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%m-%d'))['temp'].agg(['min','max'])
print (df)
       min  max
01-01    0   28
01-02    0   29
01-03    3   21
01-04    1   28
01-05    0   26
   ...  ...
12-27    3   29
12-28    4   27
12-29    0   29
12-30    1   29
12-31    2   28

[366 rows x 2 columns]
```

Last for datetimes is possible add year (be careful with leap years):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime('2000-' + df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
print (df)
            min  max
2000-01-01    0   28
2000-01-02    0   29
2000-01-03    3   21
2000-01-04    1   28
2000-01-05    0   26
        ...  ...
2000-12-27    3   29
2000-12-28    4   27
2000-12-29    0   29
2000-12-30    1   29
2000-12-31    2   28

[366 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help